# AWS Elastic Beanstalk reads from S3 bucket 13k times per hour for no obvious reason

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created an application via Elastic Beanstalk web interface, using Java environment and default settings. My Java webapp is simple and doesn't call any AWS services.

During app creation Beanstalk also created an S3 bucket, the name looks like this: `elasticbeanstalk-eu-central-1-123456789098`. I know that this bucket is necessary for storing application files and metadata. I didn't turn on sending app logs to S3.

After a couple of hours I saw that I ran out of my S3 free plan limits. The Usage Report showed that there are ~6500 `ListBucket` requests and ~6500 `ReadLocation` requests per hour to this bucket. I enabled bucket logging, so these two types of requests look like this:

```
[some id] elasticbeanstalk-eu-central-1-123456789098 [31/Jan/2017:17:01:25 +0000] x.x.x.x [some id] 61B7B2192DE0457C REST.GET.LOCATION - "GET /?location HTTP/1.1" 200 - 140 - 9 - "-" "ElasticBeanstalk-eu-central-1, aws-internal/3" -
[some id] elasticbeanstalk-eu-central-1-123456789098 [31/Jan/2017:17:01:25 +0000] x.x.x.x [some id] 8C906FEA9C4DE449 REST.GET.BUCKET - "GET /?prefix=resources%2Ftemplates%2F&max-keys=100&encoding-type=url HTTP/1.1" 200 - 319 - 10 10 "-" "ElasticBeanstalk-eu-central-1, aws-internal/3" -
```

If this matters, the bucket doesn't have the file or directory `templates` inside `resources`.

I tried restarting, redeploying, recreating everything involved. The requests keep coming even if I remove the app, the EC2 instance, the S3 bucket and simply recreate S3 bucket with the same name. I don't have other apps on my account, just 2 buckets and Route53 zone for a static website.

I'd like not only to stop this, but also to learn why it happened and how to prevent such stuff in the future.

Comment: I know that is an old question, but I have the same problem, have you understand the reason?

Comment: @Philip unfortunately not :( As far as I remember, I simply stopped using EC2 and deleted that S3 bucket, as it was only for a hobby project.